# How to make VS to copy nuget packages dll's to output directory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, material-design

I'm trying to use material design in the first time on my WPF project I install the package from nuget but when I'm trying torun it it's prompt:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Could not load file or
> assembly 'MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=df2a72020bd7962a'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.'

When I'm copying the assemblies manually to the output folder it's works.

My .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\bin\</BaseOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\bin\</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    <UseCommonOutputDirectory>true</UseCommonOutputDirectory>
     
  </PropertyGroup>
        
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MaterialDesignThemes" Version="4.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ShowMeTheXAML.MSBuild" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I tried to add

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

but it does nothing.

Comment: Is there any update about your issue? If my answer resolve your question, please mark it.

Comment: I used the xcopy method, tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET. Sdk">

   <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
     <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
     <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
     <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="MaterialDesignThemes" Version="4.6.1" />
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Auto copy is fine. Your problem did not occur. Have you tried recreating a project, does the same problem occur?

If that still doesn't work, you may need to add the msbuild event to copy the file. Use [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy).

Comment: how do i reffer to the nuget package with relative path? (so that it will work in other pcs)

Comment: If the address in your csproj is what you have to work. Then use xcopy to manually copy the dll file into the specified folder.

Comment: how on earth does this answer OPs problem? Your project-file is pretty much identical to OPs. So when you cannot reproduce the issue, you should flag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

This line is causing visual studio to omit copying of the assemblies:

```
<UseCommonOutputDirectory>true</UseCommonOutputDirectory>
```

See:

[github.com dotnet sdk - UseCommonOutputDirectory=true breaks CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies flag #23342](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/23342)

[Microsoft - build-to-a-common-output-directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022#build-to-a-common-output-directory)